# Output multidimensional array, only radio buttons showing (nested foreach loop)

Tags: php

So I'm trying to output a multidimensional array for a simple quiz. I think it's a logic error but I'm scratching my head on this one. The questions and answer choices do not show up in the browser, but all of the radio buttons do.

Any help/hints would be appreciated.

```
<body>
<?php
$q_and_ans = array(
    array('question' => 'What\'s the narrators name?',
        'ans' => array(
            'Greg Scmitz',
            'Greg Sanders',
            'Greg Smith'),
            'correct_ans' => 0),
array('question' => 'What is Greg\'s new friend\'s name?',
    'ans' => array(
        'Jose',
        'Man`enter code here`uel',
        'Manuelo'),
        'correct_ans' => 1),
array('question' => 'What beer are they drinking?',
    'ans' => array(
        'Pacifico',
        'Corona',
        'Pilsener'),
        'correct_ans' => 2),
array('question' => 'Where was the Mariscopa video taken?',
    'ans' => array(
        'Ecuador',
        'El Salvador',
        'Mexico'),
        'correct_ans' => 1),
array('question' => 'What was in the narrator\'s bowl that he failed to mention?',
    'ans' => array(
        'Shrimp',
        'Octopus',
        'Squid'),
        'correct_ans' => 0),
array('question' => 'What color was Manuel\'s shirt?',
    'ans' => array(
        'Green',
        'White',
        'Blue'),
        'correct_ans' => 2),
array('question' => 'What was printed on the beer bucket?',
    'ans' => array(
        'Corona Light',
        'Corona Extra',
        'Modelo'),
        'correct_ans' => 1),
array('question' => 'What kind of vehicle is behind Manuel?',
    'ans' => array(
        'Car',
        'Truck',
        'There is no vehicle'),
        'correct_ans' => 1),
array('question' => 'What color is the roof over the narrator\s head?',
    'ans' => array(
        'Brown',
        'Tan',
        'Green'),
        'correct_ans' => 2),
array('question' => 'What kind of animal is on Manuel\s shirt?',
    'ans' => array(
        'Aligator',
        'Duck',
        'There is no animal'),
        'correct_ans' => 0),

)
?>
```

I think the issue is in the nested foreach loop

```
<form method="post" action="">

    <?php 
        foreach($q_and_ans as $i => $q_and_an):?>

            <p><?php $q_and_an['question']?></p>
            <?php foreach($q_and_an['ans'] as $a  => $ans): ?>
            <input type="radio" value="$a" name="question[$i]"> <?php $ans ?>

            <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

"value="$a" name="question[$i]" $a and $i are not in php tags.
And I would use `<?php echo $q_and_an['question'];?>`

Comment: But now I can only select one out of 30 radios? hmmm

Comment: <?php 
   foreach($q_and_ans as $i => $q_and_an):?>
             
             <p><?php $q_and_an['question']?><?php echo $q_and_an['question'];?></p>
                <?php foreach($q_and_an['ans'] as $a  => $ans): ?>
                <input type="radio" value="<?php $a ?>" name="question[<?php $i ?>]"> <?php // $ans ?>
       <?php echo $ans;?><br>
       <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>

Comment: `<form method="post" action="">

    <?php 
        foreach($q_and_ans as $i => $q_and_an):?>

            <p><?php echo $q_and_an['question'];?></p>
            <?php foreach($q_and_an['ans'] as $a  => $ans): ?>
            <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $a;?>" name="question[<?php echo $i;?>]"> <?php echo $ans; ?>

            <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>`